# Book about an alternate history where the Cuban Missile crisis turned into full-scale war

Tags: story-identification, books

This book was published in the last decade, probably in the last five years.
The story, if I remember correctly, takes place in the present - meaning when the book was published.

In one universe a few people survive in a timeline where the Cuban Missile crisis turned into full-scale war and the world was devastated. Somehow this universe 'bleeds' into our universe, just how I don't know.

I saw the book in a bookstore but I never read it.  Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: It wasn't My Real Children, was it? Although neither future was ours in that book.

Comment: Mona Clee wrote a book called Branch Point where the narrative starts in 2062 on an Earth destroyed by the nuclear war that followed the Cuban Missile Crisis.  Time travel happens.  Changes are made to the timeline.  Ring any bells?

Comment: It is the World Next Door! THANK YOU!

Comment: Then don't forget to checkmark Emsley Wyatt's answer as accepted ;)

Comment: I'm re-issuing my "would you accept Emsley's answer", sorry for the harassment :) (don't hesitate to flag these two comments as no longer needed afterwards)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure the book in question is Brad Ferguson's [*The World Next Door*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Next_Door), even though the publication predates your time frame.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/960189.The_World_Next_Door):

> The story itself is about an Upstate New York town in the decades following a nuclear war - a war that broke out in 1962. The townspeople begin having dreams in which they appear to be living in a future world (one with computers, fast food and everything else we're familiar with here in reality) that is on the brink of their own nuclear war. Slowly, one reality begins to merge into the other...

The Cuban Missile Crisis aspect is there, as is the "bleed through" aspect.

Here's the cover:

[image: World next door cover]